# Upserting Oracle Table using Merge ORA-01747

Tags: sql, oracle

Upserting an oracle table table 1 having schema

`table1 (col1,col2,col3,Primary key :Col2)`.

and the upsert statement

```
MERGE
 INTO table1
USING (
         SELECT ? AS Col1
              , ? AS Col2
              , ? AS Col3
           FROM dual
      ) maybe 
   ON ( maybe.Col2=table1.Col2 )
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
          INSERT VALUES (
               maybe.Col1
             , maybe.Col2
             , maybe.Col3
          )
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
          UPDATE SET table1.Col1=maybe.Col1
               , SET table1.Col3=maybe.Col3
 ;
```

Result
Exception occurred
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra `SET` in the `UPDATE` section:

```
MERGE INTO table1
USING ( SELECT  ? AS Col1 , ? AS Col2 , ? AS Col3  FROM dual ) maybe
ON ( maybe.Col2=table1.Col2 )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT VALUES ( maybe.Col1, maybe.Col2, maybe.Col3 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET table1.Col1=maybe.Col1, SET table1.Col3=maybe.Col3
                                                     ^^^
```

It should be:

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET table1.Col1=maybe.Col1, table1.Col3=maybe.Col3
```

[Quick SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5dbdb/2).

The `table1` specifiers in that aren't needed, since the update is only applied against the target table anyway, but they don't hurt.